# Webview Hybrid Testing on Emulator not working but working on real Device

Tags: android, webview, appium, ui-automation, android-4.4-kitkat

I have one webview in android app and using Appium for automation Testing.
that screen contains one webview with native header with title and cross button on it.
i have used context switching using getContextHandles() which is working perfectly fine in Real device but if i run the same test on emulators then it does switch the context but not picking up the web Id's.

can anyone help why it is not running in Emulators whereas same test is running On real device and picking up the Id's.